# How to grep URLs from YouTube channel

Tags: curl, youtube, grep, lynx

As I researched the smartest way would be to use an API but when using cURL I
can find all required information in the output but its a bit messy.

```r
curl https://www.youtube.com/user/HowdiniGuru/videos | grep "watch?"
```

returns all required blocks that contain video urls:

```html
<h3 class="yt-lockup-title "><a class="yt-uix-sessionlink yt-uix-tile-link  spf-link  yt-ui-ellipsis yt-ui-ellipsis-2" dir="ltr" title="Breaking: MLA Sarwan Singh Phillaur resigned from SAD"  aria-describedby="description-id-18618" data-sessionlink="ei=fHsvWKztM8OouALZlJ24Cg&amp;feature=c4-videos-u&amp;ved=CDkQlx4iEwism5ewqLPQAhVDFE4KHVlKB6comxw" href="**/watch?v=fDqv1-kYGPI**">Breaking: MLA Sarwan Singh Phillaur resigned from SAD</a><span class="accessible-description" id="description-id-18618"> - Duration: 43 seconds.</span></h3>
```

But having difficulties to have only /watch? parts to get to the output.

```r
curl https://www.youtube.com/user/HowdiniGuru/videos | grep "watch?" | cut -f4 -d"=" | grep class | cut -f1 -d'"'
```

Does the job but it isnt very efficient as I  can imagine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cURL is not the right tool for this job:

```
lynx -dump -listonly -nonumbers https://www.youtube.com/user/HowdiniGuru/videos |
grep watch
```

[Example](//github.com/svnpenn/a/blob/939fe4e/music/music-download.sh#L33)

Comment: Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

Use `curl https://www.youtube.com/user/HowdiniGuru/videos | grep -oh "/watch?v[^\"*]\+"` to match the `/watch...` part only.